# Apply flex layout conditionally in ngFor

Tags: angular

Apply flex layout conditionally in ngFor to display textboxes in 2 column and textarea in 1 column on next line in a same row 
in angular material flex application my sample code like below

```
<div class="mb-24">
    <form class="mat-card mat-elevation-z4 p-24 br-radius-8" name="{{forminfo.form_alias}}" [formGroup]="viewformGroup">
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutfill fxLayoutGap="10px">
            <div  *ngFor="let element of formFields">
                <div [ngSwitch]="element.fields.field_type">
                    <!--TextBox want to display 50%--> 
                    <div fxFlex *ngSwitchCase="'text'">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline"  floatLabel="always">
                            <mat-label>{{element.description}}</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="{{element.form_element_id}}"/>
                        </mat-form-field> 
                    </div>
                    <!--Number/Phone  want to display 50%-->
                    <div fxFlex *ngSwitchCase="'number'">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline"  floatLabel="always">
                            <mat-label>{{element.description}}</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="number" formControlName="{{element.form_element_id}}"/>
                        </mat-form-field> 
                    </div>

                    <!--Textarea  want to display 100% in new line-->
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'textarea'">
                         <mat-form-field fxFlex appearance="outline"  floatLabel="always">
                            <mat-label>{{element.description}}</mat-label>
                            <textarea matInput formControlName="{{element.form_element_id}}"></textarea>
                        </mat-form-field> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

expected output
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AVFy.png)

Comment: Please provide minimum code of your problem context.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have updated my question with sample code

Answer (score 0):

this should work :

```
<div class="mb-24">
    <form class="mat-card mat-elevation-z4 p-24 br-radius-8" name="{{forminfo.form_alias}}" [formGroup]="viewformGroup">
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutfill fxLayoutGap="10px">
            <div  *ngFor="let element of formFields">
                <div [ngSwitch]="element.fields.field_type">
                    <!--TextBox want to display 50%--> 
                    <div fxFlex="0 1 50%" *ngSwitchCase="'text'">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline"  floatLabel="always">
                            <mat-label>{{element.description}}</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="{{element.form_element_id}}"/>
                        </mat-form-field> 
                    </div>
                    <!--Number/Phone  want to display 50%-->
                    <div fxFlex="0 1 50%" *ngSwitchCase="'number'">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline"  floatLabel="always">
                            <mat-label>{{element.description}}</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="number" formControlName="{{element.form_element_id}}"/>
                        </mat-form-field> 
                    </div>

                    <!--Textarea  want to display 100% in new line-->
                    <div fxFlex="0 1 100%" *ngSwitchCase="'textarea'">
                         <mat-form-field fxFlex appearance="outline"  floatLabel="always">
                            <mat-label>{{element.description}}</mat-label>
                            <textarea matInput formControlName="{{element.form_element_id}}"></textarea>
                        </mat-form-field> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @mustafa but it's not worked still showing in same lines

Comment: you can check on this https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-bcsrwm

Comment: Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-7yq8v6